# No suggestions chips

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I get this errror with my webhook on dialogflow. I also do not see the chips. But the normal text comes. All the other stuff and matching intents and parameter work good.

Any suggestions on how do fix this?

```
MalformedResponse expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: 'item[2]' must not be empty.
MalformedResponse expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: 'item[3]' must not be empty.
MalformedResponse expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: 'item[4]' must not be empty.
MalformedResponse expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: 'item[5]' must not be empty.
```

This is my code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = 
functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + 
  JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + 
  JSON.stringify(request.body));

function convert(agent) {
let conv = agent.conv();

let toConvert = conv.parameters["convert"]


if (toConvert.length > 60) {
    conv.ask(`To long`)
} else {
    conv.ask(`"${toConvert}" secret ${textConvert(toConvert)} secret`)
    conv.ask(`Secret`)
}


conv.ask(new Suggestion(`text`))
conv.ask(new Suggestion(`text`))
conv.ask(new Suggestion(`1`))
conv.ask(new Suggestion(`Secret`))

agent.add(conv); 


}



let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Convert', convert)

agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens that the implementation you are using is from the previous SDK which the documentation already mentions is deprecated, the first thing you should do is to migrate your code to the new AoG SDK. You can find a migration guide here:

[Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration)

Then, you can use the new library to handle the Suggestion Chips, that should fix your problem:

```
conv.ask(new Suggestions(['suggestion 1', 'suggestion 2']));
```

Don't forget to check out the library:

[Suggestion Chip v2](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip)

Answer (score 3):

The `Suggestions` object should be an array of the text suggestions to ask. You shouldn't (and can't) send more than one `Suggestions` object.

So your code should look something more like this:

```
conv.ask( new Suggestions([
  `text`,
  `text`,
  `1`,
  `secret`
]);
```